# how many integers as product of prime factors within 100?

Tags: combinatorics

Found a pretty challenging question.

How many integers from $2$ to $100$ can be expressed as the product of prime numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $x \leq y$ ?

It seems like a lot if I calculate by hand, anyone could tell a more convenient way to find it?

Comment: Hint: $x\le 7$ or otherwise $11\le x\le y$ so $xy\ge 121\gt 100$. This means you only need to consider cases $x=2,2\le y\le 47$; $x=3,3\le y\le 31$; $x=5,5\le y\le 19$ and $x=7,7\le y\le 13$.

Comment: Remember, if you like an answer, you can accept it by clicking the check mark next to that answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well by hand you would have to begin from the prime that is less or equal to $\sqrt{10}$, so 7.

So if $x=7$ then $y=7,11,13$ are the only ones.

if $x=5$, $y\in \{$ primes between $5$ and $17 \}$

if $x=3$, $y\in \{$ primes between $3$ and $31 \}$

if $x=2$, $y\in \{$ primes between $2$ and $47 \}$

So the answer may be $34$

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a significantly faster way to do it, but don't worry- blunt force actually isn't that bad here! We fix $x$ and let $y$ vary:

$x=2\implies 2\le y\le 47$

$x=3\implies 3\le y\le 31$

$x=5\implies 5\le y\le 19$

$x=7\implies 7\le y\le 13$

Otherwise, for $x\ge 11$, there is no solution for $y$.

So how many primes are there from $3$ to $47$, plus the number of primes from $5$ to $31$, plus ... et cetera? I'm sure you can do that by hand.

Answer (score 1):

I think counting by hand is the best option here. But we can be systematic about it.

It's clear that $x$ can be $2,3,5,7$, and nothing else (any other prime is too large).

- If $x=7$, then $y$ is either $7, 11$ or $13$
- If $x=5$, then $y$ can be anything from the above, or $5, 17$ or $19$
- If $x=3$, then $y$ can be anything from the above, or $3, 23,29$ or $31$
- If $x=2$, then $y$ can be anything from the above, or $2,37,41,43$ or $47$.

In total, we have $3+6+10+15=34$ possibilities.